# Tweaking parallel performance

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython

Basically, I have a large object that I want to perform some function on, that lends itself well to parallel processing. In this example, I have a large matrix and I want to compute all pairwise inner products between column vectors.

Please take a look at the following [IPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4976906/).

I realise that the `@interactive` decorator is not necessary in this context and I tried removing the `@require` decorator but its impact is negligible.

**My question is**: Is there any way available to improve the performance of the parallel machinery?

I don't know the implementation details of the `map` methods, could I avoid overhead by pushing the function that is executed in parallel to the engines in the view? I can't imagine that it is sent with every argument, though.

Chunking the argument list myself and writing a function for remote use that works on that seems silly as well.

I tried the notebook on a four core machine and the results in the notebook are for a two core machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main performance issue here is that the fortran-contiguous optimization you applied does not survive the network transfer, so `mat` on the engines is C-contiguous, not F-contiguous after the `push`.

You can see this with:

```
print mat.flags
%px print mat.flags
```

Adding:

```
%px mat = numpy.asfortranarray(mat)
```

Should get your performance back (as illustrated in my [tweaked version](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4982349/) of your notebook).

For diagnosing this issue, I did my best to isolate where the bottlenecks were.  Useful for this were the `AsyncResult.serial_time` and `AsyncResult.wall_time`.  When the `serial_time` is long, that means the task is actually taking a long time *on the engines*, rather than spending lots of time in the IPython pipes.  That led me to think that the task itself was slow on the engines, so I did the task remotely on one engine,
and it was still slow (nothing parallel involved). Here's [a notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4982709) tracking down the issue.

Side note:

The `@interactive` decorator is only necessary for functions that are *not* interactively defined (i.e. module functions, not functions defined in the notebook), so it's redundant in your notebook.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your time and effort. I didn't even remotely think that the memory layout could change.

Comment: For zero-copy sends of arrays, IPython requires that they be contiguous.  To do this, IPython uses `ascontiguousarray`, which actually ends up coercing F-contiguous arrays to C-contiguous, even though it probably doesn't need to (it may *sometimes*, depending on slicing).  I will look into what would be involved in zero-copy send of F-contiguous arrays to avoid this weird case.